# How to play customized video extension on videojs

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js, http-live-streaming

I want to change the *.ts extension in order to block some Download Manager to catch our content. Currently i'm using Videojs to stream video (HLS), but it can't play when change *.ts -> *.abc. I know that other streaming service based on HLS and Videojs can do this. Can anyone suggest me how ? Thank you

Comment: It could be that your server does set the correct content type header when you change the extension

Comment: You can try to subclass videojs's hls tech class and create custom one that can handle these extensions.